# JAXB/Maven JAX-WS: global bindings.xml references particular WSDL

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, jaxws-maven-plugin

I'm using Maven JAXWS plugin and bindings.xml file to override a Java type for a JAXB class field generated from a WSDL, but have a problem when generating Java classes from multiple WSDLs with the JAX-WS Maven plugin.

My project structure is:

```
- src
  - jaxws
    - bindings.xml
  - main
    - resources
      - wsdl
        - Wsdl1.wsdl
        - Wsdl1.xsd
        - Wsdl2.wsdl
        - Wsdl2.xsd
```

`Wsdl1.wsdl` references `Wsdl1.xsd`, `Wsdl2.wsdl` references `Wsdl2.xsd`, the two WSDLs and XSD have nothing in common. The WSDLs and XSDs cannot be modified by me.

I want to override the Java type of a particular field (`departureDate`) in a particular type (`Flight`) in `Wsdl2.xsd`.

My `bindings.xml` is

```
<bindings version="2.0" extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <globalBindings>
        <xjc:javaType name="org.joda.time.LocalDate" xmlType="xs:date"
                      adapter="my.LocalDateAdapter"/>
        <xjc:javaType name="org.joda.time.DateTime" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                      adapter="my.DateTimeAdapter"/>
    </globalBindings>
    <bindings schemaLocation="../main/resources/wsdl/Wsdl2.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Flight']//xs:element[@name='departureDate']">
            <xjc:javaType name="org.joda.time.LocalDateTime"
                          adapter="my.LocalDateTimeAdapter"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

My Maven configuration is

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I build the module with that configuration, JAX-WS processes the WSDLs one by one, but uses the same `bindings.xml` for each of them. That way, it fails during processing of `Wsdl1` due to the reference to `Wsdl2.xsd` in `bindings.xml`.

```
[INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:2.2:wsimport (default) @ my-backend ---
[INFO] Processing: file:/D:/dev/Projects/my-api/my-backend/src/main/resources/wsdl/Wsdl1.wsdl
[INFO] jaxws:wsimport args: [-keep, -s, D:\dev\Projects\my-api\my-backend\target\generated-sources\wsimport, -encoding, UTF-8, -Xnocompile, -b, D:\dev\Projects\my-api\my-backend\src\jaxws\bindings.xml, file:/D:/dev/Projects/my-api/my-backend/src/main/resources/wsdl/Wsdl1.wsdl]
parsing WSDL...

[ERROR] "file:/D:/dev/Projects/my-api/my-backend/src/main/resources/wsdl/Wsdl2.xsd"
 is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for "file:/D:/dev/Projects/my-api/my-backend/src/main/resources/wsdl/Wsdl1.wsdl#types?schema1"?
  line 11 of file:/D:/dev/Projects/my-api/my-backend/src/jaxws/bindings.xml
```

If I select just `Wsdl2.wsdl` for processing by the JAX-WS plugin, then all works fine.

```
<configuration>
    <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
    <wsdlFiles>
        <wsdlFile>Wsdl2.wsdl</wsdlFile>
    </wsdlFiles>
</configuration>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one execution of wsimport for all the WSDLs except Wsdl2.wsdl and another execution for Wsdl2.wsdl. This way you can have different configurations for each execution and specify the jaxb bindings for each differently.